# Kubernetes doesn't run image but image runs locally

Tags: node.js, express, kubernetes

Been pulling my hair out over this. I have an image that runs fine locally but when I try to run it on my kubernetes cluster I get the following message. I am not building it on kubernetes. The below log is what shows after the `kubectl log ...` command meaning the `CMD` line in my dockerfile is not working in the kubernetes cluster.

```
> chia-plot-manager-api@0.0.1 prestart /var/app
> npm run build
> chia-plot-manager-api@0.0.1 build /var/app
> rimraf build && tsc
> chia-plot-manager-api@0.0.1 start /var/app
> node build/index.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979
  throw err;
  ^
Error: Cannot find module '/var/app/build/index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:976:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:859:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! chia-plot-manager-api@0.0.1 start: `node build/index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the chia-plot-manager-api@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-06-07T00_01_43_247Z-debug.log
```

The image can be found by running `docker pull ghcr.io/128bitstudios/chia-plot-manager-api:latest`

If you want to run it locally you can type `docker run -e PORT=3000 -e CHIA_LOGS=/chialogs -e NODE_ENV=local -e DEBUG=false -p 3000:3000 ghcr.io/128bitstudios/chia-plot-manager-api:latest`

Also worth pointing out that I tried another express echo image to test and that didn't work either. It was called `alchen99/express-hello` and I have a couple of React apps running in other deployments and build/work perfectly fine.

I think it could be memory related by increased the CPU and MEM to quadrouple what they are now and it still failed. Given the error above ^^^ I think it could be something to do with the image?

My Kubernetes config is this...

deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cpm-api
  namespace: apis
  labels:
    app: cpm-api
    version: latest
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cpm-api
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      name: cpm-api
      annotations:
        linkerd.io/inject: enabled
      labels:
        app: cpm-api
        version: latest
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
        beta.kubernetes.io/arch: amd64
      containers:
        - name: cpm-api
          image: ghcr.io/128bitstudios/chia-plot-manager-api:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: 64Mi
              cpu: 10m
            limits:
              memory: 64Mi
              cpu: 10m
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /cpm-api
              port: 3000
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /cpm-api
              port: 3000
            periodSeconds: 30
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: cpm-api
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: ghcr-secret-apis
```

service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: cpm-api
  namespace: apis
spec:
  selector:
    app: cpm-api
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 5115
      targetPort: 3000
      protocol: TCP
  type: ClusterIP
```

configmap.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  LOG_LEVEL: debug
  PORT: "3000"
  NODE_ENV: local
  DEBUG: "false"
  CHIA_LOGS: "/chialogs"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cpm-api
  namespace: apis
```

ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: apis
  namespace: apis
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - apis.bradio.io
      secretName: apis-tls
  rules:
    - host: apis.bradio.io
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /cpm-api
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: cpm-api
                port:
                  number: 5115
```

Appreciate any help that comes my way and can provide more info if needed.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you are trying to build an image in the Kubernetes cluster? Are you trying to just run an existing image or build it again? Please elaborate.

Comment: Why are you even trying to run `npm build` from a prestart? You should do all of that when the image is built, not at startup time. Make yourself a `start:production` command or something that just runs stuff. As for the specific error, I would guess the build output is ending up in the wrong folder, launch a shell inside the container instead of node and look around interactively.

Comment: I should have been more clear, I am not running any commands in kubernetes. I have an image that is being pulled down via the `image` property in container on `deployment.yaml` This image runs locally fine without any previous build commands. The log at the start is what is show if I run `kubectl logs podname container name -n apis ...` so it is happening inside the image on the CMD docker command. I have edited the original text.

Comment: Your Dockerfile CMD does `npm run start` which is running the `prestart` script, which runs `build`. But whatever that is doing, in the end you don't have a `build/index.js` file so your start script fails.

Comment: @coderanger yep I thought that was the case but why does the image build in docker locally but not on kubernetes? the docker files are identical

Comment: did you figure this out?